# Android ConstraintLayout positioning children beyond visible area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

First, let me explain my goal and then I'll explain the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to create a layout for a compound control that has the following components and properties. The control has a container and a footer component where the container can hold any view/viewgroup of any size. The footer is also a container and may hold any view but in practice this is usually just one or two buttons of varying height. The footer should appear below the container and have first dibs on any available space. The container component should only be as tall as necessary (basically wrap_content behavior). However, the container may hold a scrollable view in which case it should expand in height to fit the scrollable view's content until it uses all available height minus the height of the footer.

This is really just a view where the top part may hold anything and scrolls while there is an always visible footer underneath. The only "special" part is that the control is not always supposed to occupy the entire screen.

Now, I've tried making this happen with a ConstraintLayout like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_scroll_view"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/controls_panel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollable_panel"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_header"
                android:background="#ffff00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a header" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_content"
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dynamic height content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_footer"
                android:background="#ffff00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a footer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls_panel"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dynamic_scroll_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_increment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_decrement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, as I increase the height of the content inside the scroll view, both the top of container component and the bottom of the footer component are pushed beyond the visible area. We start out like this

[image: initial state]

and then we expand the container's content until we get to this

[image: expanded and not fully visible]

As you can see, the "This is a header" view is no longer visible and can't be scrolled into view and the footer with the three buttons is also partially pushed below the visible area. How can I modify the root ConstraintLayout to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

there are view mistakes in the above xml :

- the root constraint layout width and height must fill the whole screen using match parent .
- to allow the bottom part ( the one containing buttons ) to be sticky , set its constraint to be at the bottom and allow it height to be wrap_content such that it can change in size wile sticking to bottom .
- for the dynamic scroll view , your constraints are set correctly but you need to combine the width and height to be 0dp , this way you are telling constraint layout to exactly match these constraints .

here is the full xml after editing :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/controls_panel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollable_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffff00"
                android:text="This is a header" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:background="#00ff00"
                android:text="Dynamic height content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_footer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffff00"
                android:text="This is a footer" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls_panel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_increment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_decrement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is how its behavior gonna be like after you set dynamic height to 600dp for example to allow the nested scroll view to scroll .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Saeed. Regarding setting the layout params to "match_parent" on the root layout, won't that expand the view to fill the parent instead of wrapping my content like I want?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to do the below modifications:

1. You need a vertical packed chain style `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` between the `NestedScrollView` (@+id/dynamic_scroll_view) and the `LinearLayout` (@+id/controls_panel). Of coarse to make a chain the two views must linked to each other with bi-directional position constraints.
2. The `NestedScrollView` which holds the dynamic content must have the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to avoid pushing down the `LinearLayout` in case it contains a very long content.

**Full Xml Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/controls_panel">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_panel"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollview_header"
                    android:background="#ffff00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is a header" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollview_content"
                    android:background="#00ff00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is a very small text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollview_footer"
                    android:background="#ffff00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is a footer" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls_panel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dynamic_scroll_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Reset" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_increment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_decrement"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Results with a small and a long text:**

[image: small_text]

[image: long_text]